# Firebase Simple Login - Can I watch event when user remove his account?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app any user (signed up via Firebase Simple Login) can has 1 of 3 possible statuses at a time, that is one of `active`, `deleted` and `suspended`. I kept it like this:

```
"users": {
  "simplelogin:1": {
    "username": "user1",
    "email": "user1@example.com",
    "status": "active"
  },
  // ...
}
```

Any activity that involves any user will check his/her status, if it is `deleted` or `suspended` the action cannot be done.

Normally when user choose to remove his account from my app it would be like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://my-app.firebaseio.com");

ref.child('users/simplelogin:1/status').set('deleted', function (error) {
  if (!error) {
    ref.removeUser({
      email: "user1@example.com",
      password: "secretpassword"
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is that user can remove his/her account without updating `status` to `deleted` first. For example this can be done by the user on his own browser console or on Node.js:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://my-app.firebaseio.com");

ref.removeUser({
   email: "user1@example.com",
   password: "secretpassword"
});
```

This way the user will not has his account on Firebase but the `status`  of this user that I kept above will remain `active`, and so my app will allow any activity for that user (such as someone sending him a gift, which shouldn't be allowed if his `status` has updated to `deleted` correctly.) That could be a problem. How can I update the `status` to `deleted` when user remove his/her account?

The solution I thought of is to regularly run cron job to check all the users in Firebase, try to sign up for users that *does not* has status `deleted` with random password and check if receive `EMAIL_TAKEN` error. If it can sign up, that means the user has already removed his/her account but the `status` in Firebase hasn't updated to `deleted`. In this case it has to update status to something (such as `suspicious` or `deleted`) and remove this newly signed up account again. I think this might be implemented like this:

```
// Assume this ref authenticated with admin privilege.
ref.child('users').on('child_added', function (snap) {
  var user = snap.val();

  if (user.status !== 'deleted') {
    // Assume _generateRandomPassword gives generated random password.
    var password = _generateRandomPassword();
    var credentials = {
      email: user.email,
      password: password
    };

    ref.createUser(credentials, function (error) {
      if (!error) {
        snap.ref().child('status').set('deleted');
        ref.removeUser(credentials);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I think this might not be a good solution since the system has to run for every user (that does not has `deleted` status), e.g. every night. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Interesting question. But you describe many details of your application that we don't have visibility into. Can you provide an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Thanks you @FrankvanPuffelen, I tried to improve my question. Is this one better? I will try again if it isn't :)

Comment: Thanks. That definitely helps. But the question is still unclear to me. How can a user remove their account without updating status? Show the code that does that. Why would the cron job not be a good solution? Show the code for it and say why it doesn't work/is wrong. Please read the mcve page I linked to. I know it's a long read and a lot of work. But without that work, your question will likely remain without an answer because it is too broad.

Comment: Tried again. Sorry for my explanation skill. If it's still not clear I will try to put more effort again. Thanks you for your comment.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Your use-case is clear to me now. I don't think I have a real solution though. Users should be able to delete their account and (unfortunately) you don't receive a notification of this. Your server-side check sounds like it would work, but it would be expensive. You could also do the check on-demand: when a user tries to interact with someone, check if the someone account exists (with your try-to-create-it approach). Alternatively: can you change the interaction to a model where the recipient has to accept? That would solve it cleaner I think.